# Android Studio Error:Cannot find JAR 'groovy-all-2.3.10.jar'

Tags: java, android, groovy

Hello Everyone I've just install Android Studio( I  was working in Eclips) So when I create my first project , the Android Studio  give me the folowing massege:
Error:Cannot find JAR 'groovy-all-2.3.10.jar' required by module 'gradle-core' using classpath or distribution directory 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4'

pleaseeeeeee can anyone help me I'm  new to android studio

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my antivirus had deleted that file. So I downloaded `groovy-all-X.X.XX` and I put it into the `...\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4\lib\` directory and then all was working.

Best wishes.